# I can't console.log the key that I pressed with addEventListener in my squaring calculator using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, keypress

It's not giving errors. I just did the code normally and it didn't work, then I used a function, *and then* I used a window.onload, ***and then*** I used a while loop, and it's still not working. The code looks like this:

**JavaScript code:**

```
function square() {
  function foo(n) {
    return n * n;
  }
  window.addEventListener('keypressed', checkKeyPress, false);

  function checkKeyPress(key) {
    if (key.code == '48' || key.code == '49' || key.code == '50' || key.code == '51' || key.code == '52' || key.code == '53' || key.code == '54' || key.code == '55' || key.code == '56' || key.code == '57') {
      console.log(foo(key));
    }
  }
  checkKeyPress('566');
}
window.onload = square();
```

Also, it isn't giving errors, it's just not working. This is from a while ago and I think there was something wrong with the tutorial I watched that while ago.

Comment: There is no "keypressed" event in javascript. Look for "keypress" or "keydown"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly it's not a good practice to declare a function and event listeners inside the function.
Secondly, in the example which you provided, console.log() don't call, because if statement returns false.
Thirdly, keypressed is not a valid event. There are keypress, keyup, keydown.

Comment: Not sure I follow your logic as to why it is not good practice, for example, when creating a class in js, you would create a method called something like addEvents() and inside it add the event listeners to this.foo.addEve.... That way you can actually test your class later with this.addEvents() for example.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly better answer because you could separate these into functions. Plus you probably meant keypress or keydown.

```
function foo(n){
    return n * n;
}

function checkKeyPress(key) {
    if (key.charCode >= 48 && key.charCode <=57) {
        console.log(foo(key.charCode));
    }
}

function square() {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', checkKeyPress, false); 
}

window.onload = square();
```

Comment: it's a good idea to add explanatory text to your answer, to highlight the differences between the OP's code and your code; e.g., the change from `keypressed` to `keypress` could easily be lost among the other, much larger differences in the code; even better, with some explanatory text, you can state *why* your code is better; SO is a sight for people to *learn*, not just get answers